# How do I get the data from specific tag in xml php curl response

Tags: php, xml, roblox

I need to get the `<ns1:value></ns1:value>` text from the http POST request with the following body

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF - 8"?>
      <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns2="http://roblox.com/RCCServiceSoap" xmlns:ns1="http://roblox.com/" xmlns:ns3="http://roblox.com/RCCServiceSoap12">
      <SOAP-ENV:Body>
          <ns1:OpenJob>
              <ns1:job>
                  <ns1:id>test</ns1:id>
                  <ns1:expirationInSeconds>30</ns1:expirationInSeconds>
                  <ns1:category>0</ns1:category>
                  <ns1:cores>1</ns1:cores>
                  </ns1:job>
                  <ns1:script>
                      <ns1:name>Script</ns1:name>
                      <ns1:script>
                          game.Players:createLocalPlayer(0) 
                          game.Players.LocalPlayer:LoadCharacter() 
  
                          return game:service("ThumbnailGenerator"):click("PNG", 512, 512, true)
                      </ns1:script>
                      <ns1:arguments></ns1:arguments>
                  </ns1:script>
              </ns1:OpenJob>
      </SOAP-ENV:Body>
      </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

( this is a ROBLOX RCCService version 0.3.764.0 request )

I have tried to use `simplexml_load_string($response)` but that didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - How do I handle Namespaces (Tags and Attributes with a Colon in their Name) in SimpleXML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894426/reference-how-do-i-handle-namespaces-tags-and-attributes-with-a-colon-in-thei)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can access it via using the [Namespace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.getnamespaces.php) `SOAP-ENV` and `nsi` which is inside the parent Namespace `Body` accessor.

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$ns1 = simplexml_load_string($xml)->children('SOAP-ENV', true)->Body->children('ns1', true);
[$job, $script] = [$ns1->OpenJob->job, $ns1->OpenJob->script];

var_dump($job, $script);
```

You can read more on the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) or see a [live example on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/EeiIs)

This is also covered well in the following [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48975857/simplexml-load-string-returning-a-empty-object).

Comment: Thanks, I just had to change a few values and it worked!

Comment: Take a look at the answer linked above. You should never reference a namespace by the alias/prefix.